# Selecting Distinct Values from Three Inner Join Tables

Tags: sql, inner-join

I have three tables `Order_Inventory`, `Order_List` and `Track_Order`.
I am getting replicated values for same order id in my gridView when I execute the same query here.
I wanted to get distinct values. Attached file is my query and a snapshot of database value.

Query to get track of order on the basis of `Order_Id`:

```
SELECT
  Shopping_Order_List.Order_ID AS Order_ID, Shopping_Order_List.Product_ID,
  Shopping_Order_List.Product_Name, Shopping_Order_List.Order_Product_Quantity,
  Shopping_Order_List.Order_Discount, Shopping_Order_List.Order_Price,
  Shopping_TrackOrder.Track_ID, Shopping_TrackOrder.Status, Shopping_TrackOrder.Remarks
FROM Shopping_Order_Inventory
  INNER JOIN
    Shopping_Order_List ON Shopping_Order_Inventory.Order_ID = Shopping_Order_List.Order_ID
  INNER JOIN
    Shopping_TrackOrder ON Shopping_Order_Inventory.Order_ID = @OrderID
```

Result:

```
Track_ID  Product_ID  Product_Name  Status  Remarks         Order_ID
1         1           Nexus         False   Not Assembled   4
4         1           Nexus         True    Deliverd        4
7         1           Nexus         False   Stock Incoming  4
8         1           Nexus         False   Stock Incoming  4
1         2           Galaxy Young  False   Not Assembled   4
4         2           Galaxy Young  True    Deliverd        4
7         2           Galaxy Young  False   Stock Incoming  4
8         2           Galaxy Young  False   Stock Incoming  4
1         3           Galaxy S3     False   Not Assembled   4
4         3           Galaxy S3     True    Deliverd        4
7         3           Galaxy S3     False   Stock Incoming  4
8         3           Galaxy S3     False   Stock Incoming  4
```

As you can see, I have repeated values for same order id

Comment: So, when required only 1 row per order, which remarks do you want, First or Latest?

Comment: Please share your expected output also.

Comment: Are you there? or got your solution on your own?

Answer (score 0):

The last JOINed table is not linked linked

Should be

```
SELECT
...
FROM Shopping_Order_Inventory
  INNER JOIN
    Shopping_Order_List ON Shopping_Order_Inventory.Order_ID = Shopping_Order_List.Order_ID
  INNER JOIN
    Shopping_TrackOrder ON Shopping_Order_Inventory.Order_ID = @OrderID 
                        AND Shopping_Order_Inventory.Order_ID =Shopping_Order_Inventory.Order_ID
```

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple records for tracking with same Remark for one Order Correct ?

So, to get distinct rows you should not select *track id* and use *distinct* key word to get distinct rows.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  Shopping_Order_List.Order_ID AS Order_ID, Shopping_Order_List.Product_ID,
  Shopping_Order_List.Product_Name, Shopping_Order_List.Order_Product_Quantity,
  Shopping_Order_List.Order_Discount, Shopping_Order_List.Order_Price,
  Shopping_TrackOrder.Status, Shopping_TrackOrder.Remarks
FROM Shopping_Order_Inventory
  INNER JOIN
    Shopping_Order_List ON Shopping_Order_Inventory.Order_ID = Shopping_Order_List.Order_ID
  INNER JOIN
    Shopping_TrackOrder ON Shopping_Order_Inventory.Order_ID = @OrderID
```